# simple Swift generics puzzle

Tags: generics, swift

I'm trying to learn about how to do something simple with the generics facility in Swift.  I've boiled one problem that I was facing down to a simple puzzle.  Imagine that I want to write a value type `Pair<A,B>` that has a `flip` method on it that returns a copy of the pair, but with the two values (and their types) reversed.

```
struct Pair<A, B> {
    let a: A
    let b: B

    init(first: A, second:B) {
        a = first;
        b = second;
    }

    func flip() -> Pair<B,A> {
        return Pair(self.b,self.a)
    }
}
```

When I write this I get an error on the line where I'm trying to return the new flipped pair.  `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Pair<A,B>' to type (first: A, second: B)'`

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly this is possible, since `Pair<B,A>` is a perfectly valid type in the context of the generic definition.

There are two problems with your code, namely:

1. Argument labels are required for your init method: `...(first: self.b, second: self.a)`.
2. After fixing the above, the error becomes "'B' is not convertible to 'A'". The compiler apparently does not infer that `Pair` in the definition of `flip()` refers to `Pair<B,A>` (the function's return type) rather than `Pair<A,B>`. So you must explicitly call `Pair<B,A>(first: self.b, second: self.a)`.

You may or may not consider the latter to be a bug; if so, [file a report!](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I won't consider it is a bug. Some people may expect `Pair` refer to the class itself i.e. `Pair<A,B>`