# Use function from one class in another class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So lets say I have a class called Math

```
class Math{

    func add(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int) -> Int{

        var answer: Int = numberOne + numberTwo
        return answer
    }
```

In this class there is a function which allows the user to add two numbers.

I now have another class which is a subclass of a UIViewController and I want to use the add function from the Math class, how do I do this?

```
class myViewController: UIViewController{

    //Math.add()???

}
```

Comment: `var answer` should be `let answer`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to be able to say `Math.add(...)`, you'll want to use a **class method** - just add `class` before `func`:

```
class Math{

    class func add(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int) -> Int{

        var answer: Int = numberOne + numberTwo
        return answer
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from another Swift class like this:

```
Math.add(40, numberTwo: 2)
```

To assign it to a variable `i`:

```
let i = Math.add(40, numberTwo: 2) // -> 42
```

Comment: Thank you, but why did you take out the first argument name     numberOne and kept the second one numberTwo in the function call?

Comment: It's a Swift nuance, @StephenFox. Swift leaves out the first parameter label to any function that isn't an init function. I explain it further in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815832/when-are-argument-labels-required-in-swift/24815909#24815909).

Answer (score 3):

Use `class` keyword before `add` function to make it class function.

You can use

```
class Math{
    class func add(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int) -> Int{

        var answer: Int = numberOne + numberTwo
        return answer
    }
}

class myViewController: UIViewController{

    //Math.add()???
    //call it with class `Math`
    var abc = Math.add(2,numberTwo:3)
}


var controller = myViewController()
controller.abc  //prints 5
```

This code is from playgound.You can call from any class.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
//class method
@objc func addPasswordPage(){
  //local method  
  add(asChildViewController: passwordViewController)
    }

func  add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController){

    addChildViewController(viewController)
  }
}

class UsernameViewController: UIViewController {

let login = LoginViewController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   //call login class method
   login.addPasswordPage()

  }
}
```