# Placing common methods in a separate file using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I like to place often used methods in a separate file. I found this answer [Use function from one class in another class in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921622/use-function-from-one-class-in-another-class-in-swift) but I get errors using it the way I want.

Say i want to create a method called msgBox that pops up an alert box. 
I created a separate empty Swift file and place this code in it.

```
import UIKit

class Utils: UIViewController {

    class func msgBox (titleStr:String = "Untitled", messageStr:String = "Alert text", buttonStr:String = "Ok") {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: titleStr, message: messageStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonStr, style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

I want to call it like this, but I get errors doing so. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Utils.msgBox(titleStr: "Hello!", messageStr: "Are you sure?")
```

The error looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You get errors, yet you didn't write what errors you got in your question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because you are using `self` in a `class` method. There is no `self` instance, in this case.

One thing you could do in this situation is make a class extension. In the following example, you would be able to call the `alert` method from any `UIViewController` instance:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func alert(title: String?, message: String?, buttonTitle: String = "OK") {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: .Default, handler: { action in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Notice that I changed a couple names and types, but you can use what you like.

Comment: Thanks @eric! My call now looks like this alert("Hey!", message: "Are you sure?", buttonTitle: "Yep!")