# Why do I have to pass arguments to classes in key-value form?

Tags: swift

```
class NamedShape {
    var numberOfSides: Int = 0
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides named \(name)"
    }
}
```

I have the following example class. To create a new instance, I do

```
let shape = NamedShape(name: "Test")
```

The arguments are captured by the init() function, right? However, if I do this:

```
let shape = NamedShape("Test")
```

I get a missing argument label error!

However, if I define a silly function like this:

```
func printInt(numberIn: Int) {
    println(numberIn)
}
```

I can invoke it just fine using:

```
printInt(5)
```

However, if I attempt to invoke it with the arguments formatted in the way I create a class:

```
printInt(numberIn: 5)
```

I get an extraneous argument label error!

Help a swift noob understand. Why do I need to label class arguments, but I can't label function arguments? Why are functions and classes different this way? I'm sure there's something I'm missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When are argument labels required in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815832/when-are-argument-labels-required-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because initializer functions aren’t called with a function name, the parameter types and names are used to disambiguate among multiple `init()` functions. Thus, `init()` function parameters have external names by default.

You can explicitly opt out of default parameter names with an underscore:

```
init(_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`init()` functions are special cases and all parameters are required to have an external name.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_306