# Swift: Having trouble passing an array through a method

Tags: arrays, swift, function, methods

**EDIT** I changed it according to some suggestions but I am now getting different errors

I'm trying to write a function that reads an array and if the number of elements is less than 10, then it continues to add generated values into it.

To do so I made this function:

```
func arrayValueInputter(w : Array<Int>){

    var x = 0;

    repeat{

        x += 2;

        w.append(x);

    } while w.count < 10

    print(w);
}


arrayValueInputter([1, 3, 9, 10]);

print("End Here");
```

However everytime I run it I get the error:

**OLD ERROR**

```
error: extraneous argument label 'w:' in call
arrayValueInputter(w: [1, 3, 9, 10]);
```

**OLD ERROR**

**NEW ERROR**

```
Untitled-2.swift:12:5: error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 
'w' is a 'let' constant
 w.append(x);
^
Untitled-2.swift:20:20: error: missing argument label 'w:' in call
arrayValueInputter(&arr);
```

**NEW ERROR**

I don't know what I'm missing or maybe I'm using the loop wrong. Since, I just started learning swift.

Comment: just erase the "_" before the w on method declaration. If you use _ you dont need to put argument label when you call the method

Comment: either change the signature to `func arrayValueInputter(w: inout Array<Int>) { ... }` or invoke it like `arrayValueInputter([1, 3, 9, 10]);` (but you need to make the input __mutable__ as well in both cases for `inout`).

Comment: check https://www.programiz.com/swift-programming/function-parameter-return-values#argument-label

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are argument labels required in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815832/when-are-argument-labels-required-in-swift)

Comment: I'm rolling this back a ways since it seems like you're trying to add more questions to your single question.  We prefer one question per...question, please.  If you've got another problem, feel encouraged to ask another question.

Comment: @Makoto the question is still the same question after taking on some changes the problem got more complicated but never deviated from the issue with passing an array through a function in swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The error says you have to omit the parameter label `w`
2. The other serious issue is that you can't use a literal as an `inout` parameter

---

```
var array = [1, 3, 9, 10]
arrayValueInputter(&array)
```

---

Regarding ***NEW ERROR***

Again two issues:

1. *missing argument label 'w:' in call* means: As you removed the underscore now you have to use the parameter label. The underscore indicates that the label is going to be ignored.

   ```
   arrayValueInputter(w: [1, 3, 9, 10]);
   ```
2. *cannot use mutating member on immutable value* means: All passed parameters are constants (`let`) by default. Assign the value to a new local ***var*** iable with the same name.

   ```
   func arrayValueInputter(w : Array<Int>){
       var w = w
       var x = 0
   ...
   ```

And this is Swift: No trailing semicolons.

Comment: I was trying to make it mutable and after some googling couldn't find any other way, and I tried your correction but it didn't work stuck with the errors I now defined in the edit

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks mate you're the best

Comment: @vadian I kinda wish you hadn't answered with new error, since that made rolling back the chameleon-like question a lot tougher...